# How to use inbuilt GPU and external GPU at the same time?

Tags: gpu, graphics, recording

I was trying to record a video of a game. I use an external GPU all the time, but I have inbuilt graphics (that I turned off). So I'm just wondering if I could use the inbuilt graphics for recording and external GPU for the game (at the same time).

And I use OBS btw.

Comment: Gigabyte H61M-S2P-R3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have seen others attempt a similar setup, usually resulting in several errors and other issues. In my experience, OBS performs best 'running on' the same GPU that is rendering the game. I've found that OBS doesn't have a significant impact on gaming performance, particularly in the newer cards.

While the setup you suggest is most likely possible, the performance benefits would be questionable. If you are looking to 'unload' some work from your GPU, you could investigate an external capture card or look into recording to a secondary PC, both of which are common setups I have seen in the casting community.

My advice would be to stick to having OBS capture from the GPU without worrying about the inbuilt graphics, it will most likely make life easier in the long run.

Comment: So it is possible to use the inbuilt graphics to just render the video?

Comment: On my mobo, this is a OEM feature that can be toggled through UEFI/BIOS, but I've never used it myself.  (I have an Asus ROG Maximus X Hero Wifi-AC).